# Test whether one string contains any of the words in another

Tags: perl, variables

I have a Perl program code that pulls a description string from a hash.

I have my variable `$ui` equal to the variable `$uniqueID`, but what I want is to return true if `$ui` *contains any words* in variable `$unqiueID`. But `=~` isn't working.

Is there a smart way of doing this?

```
sub getDescription {

    my $uniqueID = shift;
    my $retval;
    my $ui;

    foreach my $key ( keys %HASHLIST ) {

        foreach $ui ( @{ $HASHLIST{$key}->{uniqueID} }) {

            if ( $ui eq $uniqueID ) {
                $retval = $HASHLIST{$key}->{description};
                last;
            }
         }

         last if $retval;
    }

    return $retval;
}
```

Comment: your code is looking fine to me. Test your code by replacing  `$retval = $HASHLIST{$key}->{description};` with `print "$ui\t$uniqueID";`

Comment: Also check your `%HASHLIST` is their or not .Because your code does not have  `%HASHLIST` and show your  `=~` line

Comment: What do you mean by "=~ isn't working"? Have you tried `if ($ui =~ /$uniqueID/) {...}`?

Comment: Or perhaps `$ui =~ /\b$uniqueID\b/` which doesn't allow matches inside words.

Comment: @Mikesname please put this as an answer so I can vote it up.  It seems I was forgetting the / / when I tried using the =~ thank you.

Comment: Please give an example of `$uniqueID` and what you mean by "words". What value should be returned if it matches more than one word?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to test if one scalar variable contains another is:

```
if ($ui =~ /$uniqueID/) {
    ...
}
```

(And as [@Markus Laire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572969/perl-variable-contains-variable?noredirect=1#comment64535296_38572969) points out you can also use `/\b$uniqueID\b/` to prevent partial word matches.)

Comment: The OP wants to test whether *"$ui contains any words in variable $unqiueID"*. This will test whether it contains the whole string in `$uniqueID`.

Comment: @Borodin I thought that was unclear, but the OP asked me to post this as an answer and I obliged.

Comment: And use `/\Q$uniqueID\E/` to prevent false positive and false negative results if `$uniqueID` has regex metacharacters.

Comment: I wanted partial word matches :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose isn't clear, but it sounds like `$uniqueID` is a list of words, and you want the first entry in `%HASHLIST` whose `uniqueID` matches any one of those words

This will do that for you, but I must say that your data structure isn't ideally suited to this job

```
sub getDescription {

    my ($uniqueID) = @_;
    my %wanted = map { $_ => 1 } split ' ', $uniqueID;

    for my $ui ( values %HASHLIST ) {
        my @ids = @{ $item->{uniqueID} };
        return $item->{description} if @wanted{@ids};
    }

    return $retval;
}
```